# GeoServer WPS JTS:within convert WFS parameter

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wps

I'd like to test whether a geometry (A) is located within another geometry (B). Geometry B already exists as a layer in my GeoServer instance. The WPS process parameters are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>JTS:within</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>a</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              6.9378662109375,
              51.50532341149335
            ],
            [
              7.5750732421875,
              51.50532341149335
            ],
            [
              7.5750732421875,
              51.70660846336452
            ],
            [
              6.9378662109375,
              51.70660846336452
            ],
            [
              6.9378662109375,
              51.50532341149335
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>b</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2">
            <wfs:Query typeName="borders"/>
          </wfs:GetFeature>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Parameter b is a feature located in the `borders` layer. In `borders` only one feature exists.

After execution of this request, the following error occurs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wps:ExecuteResponse
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
  xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?" version="1.0.0">
  <wps:Process wps:processVersion="1.0.0">
    <ows:Identifier>JTS:within</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>Within Test</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>Tests if the first geometry is contained in the second geometry.</ows:Abstract>
  </wps:Process>
  <wps:Status creationTime="2018-12-19T13:40:17.849Z">
    <wps:ProcessFailed>
      <ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0">
        <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
          <ows:ExceptionText>Process failed during execution
Could not convert net.opengis.wfs.impl.FeatureCollectionTypeImpl@9a5a1f9 (lockId: null, timeStamp: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1545226817853,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=&amp;quot;GMT&amp;quot;,offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=51,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=19,DAY_OF_YEAR=353,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=40,SECOND=17,MILLISECOND=853,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0], numberOfFeatures: 0, feature: [org.geoserver.wfs.TypeInfoCollectionWrapper$Simple@6d97082]) to target type org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
        </ows:Exception>
      </ows:ExceptionReport>
    </wps:ProcessFailed>
  </wps:Status>
</wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

How do I convert the geometry B to the correct type? How do I check whether a polygon is located within a feature of a WFS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vec:CollectGeometries` process to extract the default geometry from each feature in the collection (in your case just the one feature) and returns them as a GeometryCollection, which `jts:within` should be able to use.